# Removing a class from navbar to make it collapse upon navbar item being clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a navbar that's inherited from some legacy code - and I'm trying to get the mobile version to collapse when a menu item is clicked.

http://shitnavbar.brodiedigital.io/

If you resize the window and scroll beyond the first 100vh of the page the hamburger menu will appear.

clicking will reveal the menu items

clicking a menu item WILL scroll you to correct area of page, but not collapse/close the menu

At the moment I'm using some jquery to attempt to do this by targeting just a single item on the menu - 'BIKES', with little joy:

```
$('#_bikes').on('click', function(){
    $('.menu').removeClass('active');
});
```

html for the section is

```
  <div class="menu active">
      <div class="menu_content d-flex flex-column align-items-center justify-content-center">
        <ul class="menu_nav_list text-center">
          <li><a href="#where">LOCATIONS</a></li>
          <li><a href="#_bikes">BIKES</a></li>
          <li><a href="#_concierge">CONCIERGE</a></li>
          <li><a href="#_about">ABOUT</a></li>
          <li><a href="#_enquire">ENQUIRE</a></li>
          <li><a href="#_contact">CONTACT</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Jquery isnt my strong point, but feel like im having a bit of a brain fart moment here - something very simple I'm doing wrong.

Has anyone got an insight into why clicking bikes is not removing the class 'active' from the div that has 'menu' class in it?

Comment: Your link does not open. Also please add the html code too.

Comment: Your current code says: _"When the element with the ID `_bikes` is clicked, find every element in the entire HTML document with the class of `menu` and remove the class `active` from all of those elements."_  This seems correct to me, as long as those selector are accurate.

Comment: I've since edited my original post - apologies for the missing info and thanks for you time. Chris, what you described is what I was hoping would happen, it simply does not at present.

Comment: $('.menu').removeClass('active') seems to worked, tried it on console while your menu was active.
Are you sure the eventListener fire? Add a console.log and check

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have no element with an id of `_bikes` that is why your jquery doesn't work.  Use a selector that will work:

```js
$('.menu_nav_list a').on('click', function(e){  // target all anchors in the menu nav list
    e.preventDefault();                         // prevent default action of link click
    $(this).closest('.menu').removeClass('active');  // get the closest ancestor of the link that has a class of .menu
});
```

```css
.active a {
  color:red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="menu active">
      <div class="menu_content d-flex flex-column align-items-center justify-content-center">
        <ul class="menu_nav_list text-center">
          <li><a href="#where">LOCATIONS</a></li>
          <li><a href="#_bikes">BIKES</a></li>
          <li><a href="#_concierge">CONCIERGE</a></li>
          <li><a href="#_about">ABOUT</a></li>
          <li><a href="#_enquire">ENQUIRE</a></li>
          <li><a href="#_contact">CONTACT</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: thanks for the help - i tried your code too and it worked. i really appreciate your comments as well aside each line.

Answer (score 1):

Your selector is probably the problem, the following will work for all your nav links

```
$('.menu_nav_list li a').on('click', function(){
    $('.menu').removeClass('active');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

In your code above you used .on() incorrectly and you are also targeting the element

if you wanted to target the href you would need to put the following inside the selector a[href="_bikes"] because currently you are trying to select a ID not the href in your selector.

You need to add the following code to your javascript file and it will close the menu if you click on any link inside you nav

```
$(document).on('click','.menu_nav_list a', function(){
    $('.menu').removeClass('active');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Your website has console errors.  It's from this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$('#_bikes').on('click', function(){
    $('.menu').removeClass('active');
});
</script>
```

When you run jQuery code, you need to include this code **below** the link to the jQuery file, right now you are tryint to run jQuery code before the jQuery library has been loaded.

And also wrap it in something to wait for the document to become ready

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
    $('#_bikes').on('click', function(){
        $('.menu').removeClass('active');
    });
});
</script>
```

It also looks like you are including jQuery library twice, and at two different versions.  v3.2.1 and v1.11.0

*(Also as a side note, the codebase might be legacy, but that site looks really slick!)*