# Hamburger menu requires 2 clicks before presenting the drop-down menu

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I recently fixed and issue regarding a collapsing navbar thanks to some of you fine folkes over at: [Removing a class from navbar to make it collapse upon navbar item being clicked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54576449/removing-a-class-from-navbar-to-make-it-collapse-upon-navbar-item-being-clicked)

However, I now note that in order to access the the mobile navigation menu a second time, I am required to click the hamburger icon TWICE.

site here http://shitnavbar.brodiedigital.io/

Steps to reproduce:

- Ensure browser is viewing mobile, or at least tablet width, so as the hamburger icon appears on the navbar only
- Scroll past 100vh to ensure the navbar is in field of view
- Click hamburger icon (menu will appear)
- click an navigation item, ie 'BIKES'
- Nav menu will collapse, you will be directed to the 'Bikes' section.
- Click hamburger icon (menu will NOT appear on click)
- Click hamburger icon (menu will now appear, and work as intended)

Million dollar question - What is causing the menu to not appear on the first tap/click. Why must I click/tap it a second time?

I cannot see anything happening in the dev tools on chrome to suggest why this may happen. I do however note some anomalies in the navbar movement with the chrome css debugger tool 'pesticide' active.

```
  function initMenu()
  {
    if($('.hamburger').length && $('.menu').length)
    {
      var hamb = $('.hamburger');

      hamb.on('click', function()
      {
        if(!menuActive)
        {
          openMenu();
        }
        else
        {
          closeMenu();
        }
      });
    }
  }

  function openMenu()
  {
    menu.addClass('active');
    menuActive = true;
  }

  function closeMenu()
  {
    menu.removeClass('active');
    menuActive = false;
  }
```

and I also have the following logic for clicking and anchor in the mobile navbar

```
$('.menu_nav_list a').on('click', function(e){  
    e.preventDefault();                         
    $(this).closest('.menu').removeClass('active');  
});
```

Is there a way I can combine these 2, so that clicking on a '.menu_nav_list' anchor also triggers the function closeMenu()?

Comment: Enter your code in your question please

Comment: I suspect that you forget to toggle a class or variable on click. Since you stay on the same page be sure to handle everything on navigating.

Comment: Also verify that the event bubbles correctly?

Comment: The `active` class is not added at the first tap/click. It might be a javascript issue.

Comment: I've added pertinent code - it appears because the function isn't being triggered on clicking a menu_nav_list anchor it is treating it as already active